# Inserting method differences between EF4/6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I just recently began using EF6. In the past to insert an object, it was code like this fake example (I'm writing medical software, hence, vitals) :

```
using (DatabaseThingy ObjectContext = new DatabaseThingy(Connection))
{
     vitals pcrVital =  vitals.Createvital(0, pcrEntity.idPcr, timeTaken, pulse);
     ObjectContext.vitals.AddObject(pcrVital);
     ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
     return pcrVital;
}
```

Now everything I read tells me to do it like so:

```
using (DatabaseThingy ObjectContext = new DatabaseThingy(Connection))
{
    vitals pcrVital = new vitals(){
             idVitals = 0,
             idPcr = pcrEntity.idPcr,
             timeTaken = timeTaken,
             pulse = pulse
    };
    ObjectContext.vitals.Add(pcrVital);
    ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    return pcrVital;
}
```

The first method does not exist when I use EF6. The benefit for the first method is that it would auto create a constructor with the minimum (non Nullable) columns (*edit*) if the EDMX was generated off of an already existing database. It is a simple thing to go check the database to see which are required, but having the list auto put into a constructor was quite wonderful.

Does anybody know the reason behind this, or if I've simply failed to find where it has moved to?

Comment: `that it would auto create a constructor` - what creates a constructor?  Do you mean database first?  This sentence makes no sense in it's current context.  `It is a simple thing to go check the database to see which are required, but having the list auto put into a constructor was quite wonderful.` again I have no idea what you are saying.  By `Items` do you mean `Properties`?

Comment: The database. To see which column's are non - nullable to be able to insert a new row into the database.

Comment: Personally, I've been using EF since version 4 (database first and code first) and I always made sure my EF models knew what were required before sending invalid requests to the SQL server.  [I've never been a fan of intentionally making boneheaded exceptions occur when I can prevent them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx).

Comment: This Might be wrong but i would put the default values directly into the model class constructor

Comment: I think you're partly misunderstanding - Having a constructor with the required columns prevents boneheaded exceptions. It was *auto created* with each parameter required to create a new entity. If you filled out all the parameters of the constructor, you knew for a fact you had all the data needed.

Comment: Now when I generate an EDMX from a database and attempt to create a new vital, the .Createvital( parameter 1, parameter2, parameter3) from the first example, where parameter 1/2/3 are all non-nullable columns in the database, is not created automatically.

Comment: Oh YOU generated an EDMX!  So you're talking about Database First technology with T4 templates.

Comment: Yes!  And the template for a constructor that takes the non-nullable parameters for each and every table (entity) is no longer generated automagically as of EF6.

Comment: @DFTR sorry I was having a hard time figuring out what was auto-magically being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF4 it was the **ObjectContext** that was used as compared to EF6 which uses the **DbContext**. The T4 Templates that generated the code behind are different between these versions and **the earlier default constructor is NOT available** any more.

The POCO classes created in EF6 are much lighter and cleaner than what existed in EF4. I am afraid you have to live with doing it yourself.

You can still access the ObjectContext in EF6 with the below code and access methods like AddObject.

```
(dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
```

However you need not do this anymore. It would be a better approach to use the DbSet available in the DbContext to do your Add operations.

Note: There are T4 templates available that can give you the earlier class structure with EF6, though it may not be recommended.

[image: EF6 Entity Object Generator]

Comment: So doing it yourself means you don't have to use an Object Context, you use a POCO, which is more efficient. However, you lose the itty bit of functionality that the Object Context offered you.

Comment: Thus, the second method in my original question IS in fact the Correct way as of EF6. Right?

Comment: Yes, you would lose that bit of functionality or there could be a way of modifying the T4 template to recreate the magic :)